# PrimeFaces Cache Resources

Tags: caching, resources, primefaces

In my primefaces application, I want to cache all resources, including theme.css, primefaces.css, jquery.js, .... For this purpose, I created a web filter which examines the requests and set up the cache-control response header for that resource. However, I still catch the request for all PrimeFaces resources. Does anyone know how can I cache these resources so that my web app. can have less loading time.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Put this configuration in web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
  </context-param>
```